# How to get name and other info of network upon connection?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I'm trying to determine the name and other information of a connected WiFi network. I'm trying to write an app which I want to deploy via PhoneGap where the app will only be able to work when it's connected to a specific WiFi network.

For instance it should only be able to work when I connect to my home WiFi network.

Is there a way which will allow me to return some information about the network the moment I connect to it? Some identifiers which I can use to test whether or not I am connected to the specific network in question?

Answer (score 0):

There is a wifi-plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wifiwizard

If you are looking for cordova plugins, please visit the official plugin page at:

http://cordova.apache.org/plugins

Other places for searching plugins are:

http://www.plugreg.com

http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova